# What is the correct version of GNAT Community edition, to be use with Centos 7?

Tags: linux, gps, centos7, ada, gnat

Please would somoeone be able to tell me what is the correct version of GNAT Community to use with Centos 7?

[image]

I am unable to download GNU Linux, not sure if there is an error with that version currently!

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific on the error you get? The GNAT CE 2019 GNU Linux (64-bit) version should be fine for CentOS. The other two, RISC V and ARM, are cross-compilers for embedded bare-board targets with Linux as development (host) OS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @DeeDee - This is clear to me now! I think there is an error with the GNAT site currently, as I'm unable to download the GNU version. I downloaded the GNU version, earlier in the year, luckily I still have it. So I have installed that version again! Thanks, Lloyd